# Создание объектов

Tags: java

Объясните, что происходит во время создания объекта?

```
A a = new A();
```

Вроде бы было всё понятно, что создаётся экземпляр класса A, выделяется память, вызывается конструктор, присваивается ссылка на объект, но так я думал лишь до тех пор, пока не столкнулся с повышающий и понижающим преобразованиями (upcast, downcast), просто не понимаю в чём смысл создавать например
`Animal dog = new Dog();`, если при наследовании класса `Dog`, от класса `Animal`, можно просто указать `Dog dog = new Dog();`, и как мне кажется ничего не потерять. Все принципы работы я обычно предпочитаю понимать досконально и во всех деталях т.е знать значение каждого символа, понимать логику работы и так далее. Но вот тут я к сожалению поплыл . В общем огромная просьба разъяснить или поделиться источником, в котором было бы всё это более менее расписано.

Comment: Если вы написали кусок кода работающий с `List`, то можете туда передать `LinkedList` или `ArrayList`. Удобно.

Comment: Ну например `Animal pet = catsAreBest ? new Cat() : new Dog();`

Answer (score 0):

Ты создаёшь экземпляр класса animal и при создании объекта cat и например dog. Но они буду создаваться с методами animal а реализация этих конкретных методов будет браться из dog и cat. Но хотя объекты кот и собака разные объекты но ты можешь их например сохранить в один список. Потому что это объекты animal. И работать с этим списком. Или ты можешь создать объект указав перед =  интерфейс с методами который тебе нужен. И по этому интерфейсу группировать объекты разных классов. И работать с ними как будто это объекты одного класса.
Например можно создать список который будет принимать объекты типа animal.  Туда можно будет положить и cat и dog